Enabling SSO in Teams Toolkit (Notification Bot)
I'm following this article to enable SSO in a new notification bot
at the end of it, you should map razor pages
screenshot from the article
It looks like the article is assuming that I will have a web application builder. while in the notification bot, we have a host builder.
screenshot from the code
any advice on what am I missing here?
I've tried to create a tab application and it is working perfectly. but I want to be able to create it for a notifications bot with a timer trigger.

Refer the sample to implement SSO in the notification bot- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/44a2ad323edd4f663a243bd2b5324e6897ab4d81/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore/BotConversationSsoQuickstart

It would be great if you can share why you need SSO for a notification bot.
I'm assuming you want to leverage SSO to get a user token to call some APIs in the notification bot. If this is your scenario, here's what you can do in general：

Add a bot command to let users be able to login to your app.
Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication to add authentication to your app.
In your notification code, call related methods from BotFramework SDK to acquire a token to call related APIs.

